# Subscribing multiple handlers to DOM Events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am attempting to subscribe events by the CSS class.  I have two handlers, defined as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.refresh-cart').click(
        function(e) {
            alert('refreshing');
        });
    
    $('form.ajax').submit(
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post(
                this.action,
                $(this).serialize(),
                function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert('post'); },
                'text');
        }
    );
});
```

When these handlers overlap, I am not getting the expected functionality.

This code works correctly, by alerting 'post' and submitting an ajax request.

```
 <form action="page.html" method="post" class="ajax">
     <input type="text" name="Sample" value="SampleValue" />
     <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

This code works correctly, by alerting 'refreshing'

```
  <div class="refresh-cart">Refresh Widget</div>
```

However, when these overlap (such as in the following example), only the 'refresh-cart' subscriber fires.

```
 <form action="page.html" method="post" class="ajax">
     <input type="text" name="Sample" value="SampleValue" />
     <input type="submit" class="refresh-cart" />
 </form>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make both handlers fire?

Comment: I don't find any changes in the two codes you have mentioned above

Comment: @Abdul Kader, edit made.  The first code sample does not have the class on the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine for me..

You do have to close the first alert box, though, before the second can be shown..

your code live at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/W3zC4/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried submitting the form from the click handler?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.ajax').submit(
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post(
                this.action,
                $(this).serialize(),
                function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert('post'); },
                'text'
            );
    });

    $('.refresh-cart').click(
        function(e) {
            alert('refreshing');
            $('form.ajax').submit();
            return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: I haven't tried this because it doesn't accomplish the objective.  There are multiple ajax forms on the page.  Only one of them should refresh the cart.  There are also multiple elements which refresh the cart, only one of which is a form.

Comment: Those sentences should be in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me as well. I think you should also consider jquery form plugin [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for ajax submit and changing the input type from submit to button